# AsyncTask looping infinitely when using WallpaperManager on LineageOS 15.1

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

#### [Solved] See answer below

My app strangely runs in infinite loop wildly. This is a simple code to download an image and apply as wallpaper.

But when removing this line of code, the loop disappears, that is, `AsyncTask` returns to work as expected:

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(weakContext.get()).setBitmap(bitmap);
```

I have already thought that the problem could be `WeakReference`, but even by running the code inside the `onPostExecute()` method using a `Listener` to execute the changes within the `Fragment` the problem persists.

---

#### EDIT

## First Attempt: Using AsyncTask

```
public class WorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private static final String TAG = "WorkerTask";
    private WeakReference<Context> weakContext;
    private WeakReference<ImageView> weakImage;
    private Bitmap wallpaper;
    private WallpaperListener wallpaperListener;

    WorkerTask(Context context, ImageView imageView, WallpaperListener listener){
        weakContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
        weakImage = new WeakReference<>(imageView);
        wallpaperListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: ");

        if (url[0].isEmpty()){
            throw new NullPointerException("URL Bad formatted");
        }

        /* Network */
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url[0])
                .build();
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            /* Generate Image */
            wallpaper = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).byteStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (response != null) {
                response.close();
            }
        }

        return wallpaper;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

        try {
            WallpaperManager.getInstance(weakContext.get()).setBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

---

## Second Attempt: Using Threads and Runnables

```
public class WorkerFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "WorkerFragment";
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textView;
    private Bitmap wallpaper;

//    String UrlApi = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1511736515797-8aab81ec7e35?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=966f3c728ebb930b49192fdbf14b55e0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1534&q=80";
    String UrlApi = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535632788826-78ca9d09d2e7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=bb651ad5967f2074c98b8c30ae2fc442&auto=format&fit=crop&w=695&q=80";

    public WorkerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_worker, container, false);

        imageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated: ");

        final Runnable setImage = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "run2: ");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(wallpaper);
                setWallpaper(wallpaper);
            }
        };

        Runnable getImage = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "run1: ");
                wallpaper = getWallpaper();
                imageView.post(setImage);
            }
        };

        Thread workerThread = new Thread(getImage);
        workerThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getWallpaper(){

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(UrlApi)
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    private void setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap){
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        try {
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

---

Logcat:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: where are you calling the AsyncTask?

Comment: @Juan yes! I've edited my ask with fragment code who calls and execute asynctask

Comment: Can you post the usage of WorkerFragment class? I hope you are using it in a list or in some loop

Comment: Can you move the WorkerTast and the task.execute to onResume() instead of onCreateView() to see if you get the same result?

Comment: @Juan onResume() happens the same

Comment: @ViswanathKumarSandu code added, see my ask again. thanks!

Comment: I have ran your code in emulator Android 27 and works ok, it doesn't loop and it sets the wallpaper, so the problem must be somewhere else. The only thing I did was to remove the WallpaperListener that is not actually used. A couple of sugestions, in a Fragment when you call getContext() make sure you don't get null, and when using weak references, before using what get() returns, check it doesn't return null. (For this test everything worked ok out of the box)

Comment: @Juan thanks for your help. I've updated again my ask with more code. This time I was trying to update wallpaper using `threads and runnables` but it falls again in a loop.

Comment: The first attempt works fine. The problem has to be in something you hadn't posted. Can you add your manifest? Are there any other activities? Or additional code that could be firing the activity over and over... Also try cleaning the project from android studio.

Comment: @juan you're right. I've tested in another phone and it works perfectly. Also i've tested on emulator and run without problems. But I think i was my rooted phone using a custom rom, but I don't know what.

Comment: Most surely it has to do with the "rooted" part of your comment :)

Comment: @juan i'll check it now. I have two same devices one rooted and another stock rom. Lets see! Anyway, thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what made the Thread loop infinite, but not the reason. In simple terms, it is a **LineageOS 15.1 feature** called [StyleInterface](https://lineageos.github.io/android_lineage-sdk/reference/lineageos/style/StyleInterface.html) to change the colors of the system to match the wallpaper or time. When setting to match wallpaper, the bug occurs.

I'm testing on rooted device using a Custom ROM. It doesn't happen on stock rom devices.

---

#### Bugged feature

[image]
.

---

#### Gif demo

[image]